# Prevent a view in chaplin.js from being rerendered

Tags: view, backbone.js, navigation, coffeescript, chaplinjs

I'm playing around a little with a [Chaplin](http://chaplinjs.org) App and try to add a class to a link in my navigation depending on the routed URL.

```
# navigation_view.coffee

initialize: ->
  super
  @subscribeEvent '!router:changeURL', @setActiveNavigation

setActiveNavigation: (path) ->
  $('nav a[href="/' + path + '"]').addClass "active"
```

That works pretty well for the fraction of a second until the whole navigationView is being rerendered. `autoRender` is set to `false`. Does anybody know how to prevent the view from being rerendered?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I forgot about the `@subscribeEvent 'startupController', @render` and now without that it works fine.